# How do I edit a @{ that powershell automatically puts registry keys ins?

Tags: powershell

so I have a powershell command that grabs a registry key. But when using select-pattern, it always sticks the whole key within a line, and I've been googling everywhere but no where is telling me how to only grab certain language from the line, and not return the full like. Like below:

```
Line       : @{t0_recursive=\\ad\; t7_recursive=\\ad\chrolit; t5_recursive=\\ad\arolit; t3_recursive=k:\; 
             t9_recursive=\\ad\fwrolit; t10_recursive=\\ad\larolit; t15_recursive=\\ad\slrolit; 
             t6_recursive=\\ad\brolit; t11_recursive=\\ad\mirolit; t14_recursive=\\ad\sfrolit; 
             t12_recursive=\\ad\nyrolit; t2_recursive=j:\; t16_recursive=\\ad\enfcases; t1_recursive=f:\; 
             t8_recursive=\\ad\drolit; t4_recursive=m:\; t13_recursive=\\ad\plrolit; t17_recursive=C:\ENFProcessing; 
             t129=c:\enfprocessing; t99=\\ad\slrolit; t9=\\ad\; t84=\\ad\sfrolit; t69=\\ad\plrolit; t54=\\ad\nyrolit; 
             t39=\\ad\mirolit; t279_recursive=C:\Users; t264=\\ad\fwrolit; t249=\\ad\drolit; t24=\\ad\larolit; 
             t234=\\ad\chrolit; t219=\\ad\brolit; t204=\\ad\arolit; t159_recursive=\\AD.SEC.GOV\Projects; 
             t144_recursive=\\AD.SEC.GOV\users; t114=\\ad\enfcases; 
             PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe 
             Acrobat\DC\FeatureLockDown\cTrustedFolders\cAlwaysTrustedForJavaScript; 
             PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Adobe 
             Acrobat\DC\FeatureLockDown\cTrustedFolders; PSChildName=cAlwaysTrustedForJavaScript; 
             PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry}
```

I get this output, but can't just return PSPath and the C:\Users* from the line, it always returns the full line.

Why is this?

```
$value = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC\TrustManger\cTrustedFolder'  2>NULL | findstr : | measure-object -line | select-object -expandproperty lines ; if ( $value -lt 1 ) { echo 'PASSED, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC\TrustManger\cTrustedFolder is NULL' } else { $value2 = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC\TrustManger\cTrustedFolder' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -Name t*} |Select-String -Pattern 'c:\\users*' | select -ExpandProperty Line| findstr /i /V /c:Desktop, /c:downloads|format-list LineNumber,Line
```

I tried googling how to edit lines in powershell, to no avail.

Comment: Why are you mixing `Select-String` and `findstr.exe` use?

Comment: [Edit] the question and explain in plain English what you are trying to get from the registry.

Comment: So basically my boss wanted me to make a powershell command that would search for any subkeys under that adobe location and only focus on the ones that have c:\users. Then of the ones that have c:\users if they don't have c:\users\desktop or downloads, then flag it as a finding. So I'm trying to return any c:\users that dont have either downloads or desktop

Answer (score 0):

Take out findstr. It turns objects to strings.

The get-childitem output is a bit confusing for the registry.  The formatting file `$PSHOME\Registry.format.ps1xml` runs get-itemproperty.  Use get-itemproperty to get registry values.

I have a replacement for get-itemproperty that can be used for recursive searches here: [Use PowerShell to search for string in registry keys and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963661/use-powershell-to-search-for-string-in-registry-keys-and-values/54618711#54618711)

For example:

```
get-childitem -recurse hklm:\software\adobe | get-itemproperty2 | 
  ? name -like distiller*

Path                                                  Name      Value  Type
----                                                  ----      -----  ----
HKLM:\software\adobe\Acrobat Distiller\10.0\Uninstall Distiller     1 DWord
```